# "PKIX path building failed: (...) unable to find valid certification path to requested target" despite valid Cert chain (according to otherprograms)

Tags: java, gradle, repository

My Gradle project tries to access a private Repo that needs a secure connection.

The server offers a Certificate including the entire chain (Root->Intermediate->Server, checked with  browser and the Windows Certificat Tool).
The Root certificate is listed in cacerts as trusted. Firefox and Chrome also trust the root certificate.

When I connect to the server via a browser, the connection is trusted, however when I do the same via the gradle project, we get the error that no valid certification path can be found.
The connection via the broser is done as a TLSv1.3 connection, so we know that the server accepts such conenctions.

What other causes could throw this error?
How to deal with it (other then adding the server cert as trusted)?

In case we want to write to the repo:

```
Root cause: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not write to resource '[Path URL changed for question]'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    (...)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    (...)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    (...)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at (...)
```

If we want to read from the repo:

```
> Could not GET '[Path URL changed for question]'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Tried allowing insecure protocols, defining that the known good connections TLSv1.3 are used, as suggested in the seccond stack trace.

Adding the certificate to cacert is only accepted as a last resort option.